# TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined after upgrade to Nextjs 11

Tags: next.js

Have upgraded my project to nextjs 11 and unfortunately some of my code is erroring out.

I have equally upgraded React from 16.0.0 version to 17.0.0 so I could then upgrade to next.js.

This is the code snippet that is erroring out and its located in my next.config.js file:

```
config.module.rules[1].oneOf.forEach((moduleLoader, i) => {
            Array.isArray(moduleLoader.use) && moduleLoader.use.forEach((l) => {
                if (l.loader.includes("css-loader") && l.options.modules && l.options.modules.exportLocalsConvention) {
                    l.options = {
                        ...l.options,
                        modules: {
                            ...l.options.modules,
                            exportLocalsConvention: "camelCase",
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

If I remove the code entirely a different error pops up related to svg config on the same file :

```
webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
            // svg to react component loader 
            config.module.rules.push({
                test: /\.svg$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: '@svgr/webpack',
                    options: {
                        "svgoConfig": {
                            "plugins": [{ "cleanupIDs": false }]
                        }
                    }
                }],
            })
```

Any ideas on what is happening?

I know they have new related features but not entirely sure how to go about it and ensure my project runs similarly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next.js 11 now uses webpack 5 under the hood so you need to update your webpack config accordingly.

There is a small migration guide [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/upgrading#webpack-5), but it does not cover all the changes obviously.

I think you can also opt-out of webpack 5 for now, if you want to update Next.js but don't want to mess with webpack config for now:

```js
// add this key in your next.config
module.exports = {
  webpack5: false,
}
```

Comment: that issue effectively disappeared but having another one now in some of my pages:
```Server Error
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports```

Comment: this error is coming up on the following function in the _document.js file:
```class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return { ...initialProps };
  }```

Comment: That is completely different issue, and as it said you probably forgot to export some page component?

Comment: I have commented that bit of code out and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error when list children got no key.just make sure they got a unique key each one.